# Place two subsections next to each other

Tags: positioning, subsection

Is it possible to place two subsections next to each other instead of below each other?

If not: What would be an alternative?

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
\end{itemize}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use twocolumn, minipage or other multicolumn packages.

Comment: @Sylvia Can you please stop using the `overleaf` tag for questions which are not specific to overleaf?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, yes, of course!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could place the subsections in side-by-side `minipage` environments.

[image]

Do ask yourself, though, if you even need the subsection-level headers.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{showframe}  % show edges of textblock

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}% % be sure not to leave a blank line
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, prompted by a comment by @JohnKormylo: In case the list itemize are entire sentences rather than single words, it's a good idea to insert a whitespace buffer between the two `minipage` environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{enumitem}   % tools to modify 'itemize' environments
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{showframe}  % show edges of textblock
\usepackage{lipsum}     % filler text

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\RaggedRight % suspend full justification

\begin{itemize}[left=0pt,noitemsep]
    \item \lipsum[1][1]
    \item \lipsum[1][2]
    \item \lipsum[1][3]
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}% 
\hfill % be sure not to leave a blank line
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\RaggedRight % suspend full justification

\begin{itemize}[left=0pt,noitemsep]
    \item \lipsum[1][4]
    \item \lipsum[1][5]
    \item \lipsum[1][6]
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You just overtake me in seconds, :-D

Comment: I would have added a `\columnsep` gap getween the two.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Please see the addendum I just posted. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This shows a `paracol` solution.  You could also use `multicol*` (unbalanced) with `\columnbreak`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \subsection{Subsection 1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
  \end{itemize}
\switchcolumn
  \subsection{Subsection 2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
  \end{itemize}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```